# Searching for a font with special ampersand

Tags: fonts, ampersand

I want to use a special ampersand in a document. I’m therefore looking for, and failing to find, a font that contains an ampersand that looks as follows:

[image: specimen] (That is, a slashed, rounded “E” letter.)

<sub>(For the record, this is the “Chalkduster” font, and it’s too casual for my use; I’m not searching for a script typeface.)</sub>

I distinctly remember having seen a sans serif typeface that featured such an ampersand but I am unable to find it again. For the record, Detexify doesn’t turn up anything either.

Either of two things would help me:

1. Can somebody identify a commonly-available or freely available typeface that includes such an ampersand?
2. Does anybody know how I could “draw” this character using LaTeX, in a way that would make it usable as a character?

(This is also an experiment: is such a question on-topic enough for the site? Feel free to state your opinion in the comments, and vote to close if you’re so inclined.)

Comment: Perhaps you could make such a glyph on your own using fontforge

Comment: While searching for just the right ampersand myself once, I found a pageful of them at http://hail2u.github.io/google-webfonts-ampersands.html (all open source fonts available from Google). Of all the slashed-E ampersands I see there, all are script-like fonts (not counting a few very blocky novelty-display fonts) and most do not have the full through-slash. The closest I see to what you describe is [Yellowtail](http://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Yellowtail), though it is slanted and likely a bit too bold.

Answer (score 11):

Halvorsen (below)? You should probably ask at the typophile.com forums.

[image: Halv]

**Edit** how about Graphite? Casual, but not as casual as chalkduster?

[image: graphite]

Comment: Close, but not quite – I’m really in love with the slash through the whole letter. The Halvorsen specimen looks more like a currency symbol than an ampersand.